# How to show the integral symbol on this site?

Tags: support, mathjax

On this question: [How do I use substitution in integrals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142089/how-do-i-use-substitution-in-integrals) there are examples of what I want. I just want to show integrals on my questions like that. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you asking for a tutorial on writing equations so they display correctly? See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/480/742), and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117).

Comment: Click on "edit" on that (or any other) page and you'll see how it was done.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: He may not be able to edit (low rep). But right-clicking on an equation (at least on Firefox) will open a dialogue window that should allow him to see the MathJax code displayyed.

Comment: @Arturo: Low-rep users can suggest edits, therefore can edit. In fact, anonymous users can suggest edits, so surely a user with 108 points of reputation can...

Comment: @Asaf: All these "new-fangled" things. When *I* was a low-rep user, the edit button did not even appear. And we had to post during snowstorms, up-hill, both ways!

Comment: There's a workaround explained in [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1776/) - every user can view the source. Another possibility would be to view the source of the page you're viewing (Ctrl+U in Firefox), but it's more difficult to find it there and you can see only mathjax syntax there, not markdown.

Answer (score 13):

For basics about [MathJax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax), which is used at this site to typeset math, see [editing help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) or [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Specifically for integrals:

You can get integral like this:
`$$\int x^2 \, dx = \frac{x^3}3 +C$$`
$$\int x^2 \, dx = \frac{x^3}3 +C$$
Notice `\,` in front of dx - this adds a small space between them, so it looks better.

You can write multiple integrals like this:
`$$\iint r(\cos\varphi+\sin\varphi)\,d\varphi\,dr$$`
$$\iint r(\cos\varphi+\sin\varphi)\, d\varphi\, dr$$
Writing `\iint` gives you better spacing than just `\int\int`. For triple integrals:
`$$\iiint 1 \,dx \,dy \,dz$$`
$$\iiint 1 \,dx \,dy \,dz.$$

If you want definite integrals, you can add bounds like this:
`$$\int_0^1 x^2 \,dx= \frac13$$`
`$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} r \,d\varphi\,dr$$`
`$$\iint_{x^2+y^2\le 1} x+y \,dx\,dy$$`
$$\int_0^1 x^2 \,dx= \frac13\\
\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} r \,d\varphi\,dr\\
\iint_{x^2+y^2\le 1} x+y \,dx\,dy$$
Notice that if the subscript or superscript has more than one symbol, you have to enclose it in `{}`, e.g. `$\int_{-\pi}^\pi$` or `$\int_0^{2\pi}$`.
(Or course, you can use curly brackets even if there is only one symbol, e.g. `$\int_{0}^{1}$` works fine; but they are not necessary.) Here is what these examples look like: $\int_{-\pi}^\pi$; $\int_0^{2\pi}$ and $\int_{0}^{1}$.

Another useful thing - if you are using substitution or per partes you might want to indicate what you are doing, e.g. like this:
`$$\int \cos x \sin x \,dx = \left| \begin{array}{c} u=\sin x \\  du=\cos x\,dx \end{array}  \right| =\int u \,du$$`
$$\int \cos x \sin x \,dx = \left| \begin{array}{c} u=\sin x \\  du=\cos x\,dx \end{array}  \right| =\int u \,du$$
`$$\int x\cos x\, dx = \left| \begin{array}{cc} u=x & v'=\cos x \\ u'=1 & v=\sin x \end{array} \right|  = x\sin x - \int \sin x \,dx$$`
$$\int x\cos x\, dx = \left| \begin{array}{cc} u=x & v'=\cos x \\ u'=1 & v=\sin x \end{array} \right|  = x\sin x - \int \sin x \,dx$$

Integrals are rendered slightly differently in centered formulas (marked by pairs of dollars) and inline mode, compare this:
`$$\int_a^b f(x) \,dx,$$ $\int_a^b f(x) \,dx$ and $\int\limits_a^b f(x)\,dx$.`
$$\int_a^b f(x) \,dx,$$ $\int_a^b f(x) \,dx$ and $\int\limits_a^b f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: For double integrals, `\iint` rather than `\int\int` produces two integral signs with the proper amount of space between them.

Comment: I did not know that. But if I want $\int_0^1 \int_0^1$, I use `\int` twice, right? I made the post CW, feel free to edit it.

Comment: Yes, `\int` twice, or `\iint_{}` with the domain of integration in the subscript, which can be an awkward alternative or not, depending on the domain.

Comment: @did I've added some example into the post. I hope it's approximately like what you meant.

Comment: For completeness, let me note that the triple integral symbol $\displaystyle \iiint$ is also defined: `\iiint`. We also have the contour integral symbol $\displaystyle \oint$ `\oint`.

Comment: @WillieWong I've added \iiint. I did not write about contour integrals, since I use them only rarely. Feel free to edit my post or add a separate answer with some examples of contour integrals, if you thing it would be useful.

Comment: [This post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13157/tex-integral-support/) mentions how the integral sign can be made larger.