# What about overview of basic LaTeX commands here in meta?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I have feeling that something like this has been asked before, but I cannot find such post, so my memory might be fooling me.

Do you think that giving here examples of usage of the most frequently used LaTeX constructions here at meta could be useful for our users? I tried to write down something for integrals here: [How to show the integral symbol on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4497/how-to-show-the-integral-symbol-on-this-site/4499#4499)

If you think that this would be a good thing, what topics to you think should be covered.

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that now we already have [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

If we decide to do something like this, I like the way LaTeX help is organized at [sosmath](http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewforum.php?f=16), so I would go with something similar to their help:

- Basic commands (superscripts, subscripts, bracket for sets $\{\}$, inequalities $\le$ and similar stuff that is frequently used, but does not fall nicely into other categories; `\operatorname` and `\text` could be mentioned here)
- fonts and some frequently used symbols (like $\pm$, $2\mid4$, $2\nmid 3$, $\infty$, $\vec{a}$)
- alignment and multiline formulas (perhaps also difference between inline math and centered formulas could be explained there)
- polynomials, radicals, fractions
- Greek letters
- trigonometry
- limits
- sums
- derivatives
- integrals
- matrices
- sets, operation with sets ($\cap$, $\subseteq$, $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty$ and similar stuff; notation for intervals - $[a,b]$ or $\langle a,b \rangle$ but not $<a,b>$)
- (maybe) combinatorics (also from the top of my head I can only think of binomial coefficients, so this might fall under frequently used symbols)
- (maybe) tables (array, `\hline`, etc.)
- (maybe) elementary number theory (divisibility, congruences, Jacobi symbols)

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117 covers the latex commands.

Comment: tables are not really supported in MathJax, so don't bring that in. For a list of supported MathJax commands see http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm

Comment: @WillieWong I know that tabular environment does not work here; I meant examples using array there. (Which is the only reasonable way I am able to use here, to create a table.) But, as you can see, I've added *maybe* to that item, as I was not entirely sure it would be useful.

Comment: BTW now I found this: [How do I insert a table when asking a question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/how-do-i-insert-a-table-when-asking-a-question/) So inserting tables is already explained at meta.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think compiling yet another LaTeX cheatsheet is a good use of meta when there are so many other great references available online. Many of them are linked to in the comments and answers to the previous question "[where is the latex reference please](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/934/856)".

On the other hand, I do feel that those resources need to be made more visible. They ought be linked to in the help text, both on the side of the Ask a Question form, and in the [formatting help page](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help). A link or two to a quick reference under the LaTeX bullet point wouldn't hurt.

Comment: What *should* be documented somewhere is the commands from which LaTeX packages are supported (amsmath seems to be; let's test a few more: mathds: $\mathds{C}$, mathtools: $\coloneqq$, cancel: $\cancel{p}$ — OK, none of them seems to be supported).